# return absolute values when subtracting sets

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to create a simple Statistical Process Control program. I need absolute values for my moving range. The absolute values are the difference of the successive data points.

I've tried adding 'abs()' throughout the code but no luck.

```
values = [19,27,20,16,18,25,22,24,17,25,15,17,20,22,19,16,22,19,25,22,18,20,16,17]

move_range = [x-y for x, y in zip(values, values[1:])] 

print (move_range)
```

Current output is:

```
[-8, 7, 4, -2, -7, 3, -2, 7, -8, 10, -2, -3, -2, 3, 3, -6, 3, -6, 3, 4, -2, 4, -1]
```

I want these in absolute values.

Comment: How did you use abs? What happened when you did?

Comment: I added it at print (abs(x, move_range))

Comment: `abs` only works on a single input, as I'm sure you saw in the docs. What result did you get from that print statement?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that using `abs` when taking differences should work. That is,

```
[abs(x - y) for x, y in zip(values, values[1:])]
```

gives

```
[8, 7, 4, 2, 7, 3, 2, 7, 8, 10, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much. I think I'm stuck in beginner purgatory!